# Better alternative to long list of if statements

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I have an int called `dayCounter` that runs 1 to 7. And i have a String called `day`. `dayCounter` increments every 10 seconds using `TimerTask`.

I use the following if statement inside the `private void run()` method used for `TimerTask`::

```
if (dayCounter == 1) {
    day = "Monday";
}
```

I have an if statement like this for every day of the week. Is there a more efficient way which gets the same result. I was thinking maybe creating an array with holds String month and then increment it some way. But i wouldn't know how to go about it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Other then a if statement you can use a switch case with the counter

```
switch(dayCounter){
    case 1:
        day = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2: 
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
}
```

Although this is another way to do it they both create the same byte code and the only difference between these two options is the readability of the code.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way would be to use an array for the days:

```
public class Demo {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getDay(1));
        System.out.println(getDay(7));
     }

     // Returns the corresponding day for the given dayCounter.
     // Assumes that dayCounter goes from 1-7.
     private static String getDay(int dayCounter) {
         String[] days = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
               "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
         return days[dayCounter - 1];
     }
}
```

If your counter goes above 7 (e.g. you are incrementing it by 1 in each timer step), you might want to be interested in this version, which basically loops through all available days:

```
public class Demo {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getDay(1));
        System.out.println(getDay(7));
        System.out.println(getDay(8));
        System.out.println(getDay(13));
     }

     // Returns the corresponding day for the given dayCounter.
     // Maps dayCounter to the range of 1-7, assumes that dayCounter
     // goes from 1-Integer.MAX_VALUE.
     private static String getDay(int dayCounter) {
         String[] days = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",
               "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
         return days[dayCounter % 7];
     }
}
```

Or you could use `DateFormatSymbols` to retrieve the weekdays and get them even (nearly) automatically translated for you:

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;

public class Demo {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getDay(1));
        System.out.println(getDay(7));
     }

     // Returns the corresponding day for the given dayCounter.
     // Assumes that dayCounter goes from 1-7.
     private static String getDay(int dayCounter) {
        String[] days = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getWeekdays();
        return days[dayCounter];
     }
}
```

Or for Java 8 and later, the currently preferred way might be to make use of new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API (you can play around with the method arguments). This API includes a handy [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getDay(1));
        System.out.println(getDay(7));
    }

    // Returns the corresponding day for the given dayCounter.
    // Assumes that dayCounter goes from 1-7.
    private static String getDay(int dayCounter) {
        return DayOfWeek.of(dayCounter)
                 .getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault());
    }

}
```

And if you just want to replace the `if` statements, go with the `switch-case` as mentioned in Ryan's answer.

Comment: Unless you expect the days of the week to change some time, you'd be better off using an enum.

Comment: @azurefrog: I actually started with an enum, but figured it might be too complicated for a start. Especially when there is already a built-in enum for that purpose. In general a valid point, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an array of strings, dayOfWeek, one for each day of the week.  Then you use dayCounter as as index into the array.  For example, if dayCounter = 1, then dayOfWeek[dayCounter] would be "Monday".  This way you need only one statement to get the name of the day of the week.